# Configuring Exim as a mail relay on Debian using Ansible

Tags: debian, ansible, exim

I am trying to configure exim on multiple Debian servers to be mail relays using Ansible.

I would like to use the Debian way of configuring things - using debconf. Ideally so that I just pass in the few basic configuration options, and Debian generates the Exim configuration.

I have got it working, but it seems overly complex and doesn't feel right.

Tasks:

```
- name: Install exim4
  apt:
    name:
      - exim4
      - exim4-daemon-light
      - exim4-config
    state: present

- name: install /etc/exim4/passwd.client
  copy:
    src: exim4-passwd.client
    dest: /etc/exim4/passwd.client
    owner: root
    group: Debian-exim
    mode: 0640

- name: configure exim4-config
  debconf:
      name: 'exim4-config'
      question: '{{ item.key }}'
      vtype: 'string'
      value: '{{ item.value }}'
  with_dict:
    exim4/dc_eximconfig_configtype: mail sent by smarthost; no local mail
    exim4/dc_localdelivery: mbox format in /var/mail/
    exim4/dc_local_interfaces: '127.0.0.1 ; ::1'
    exim4/dc_minimaldns: 'false'
    exim4/dc_other_hostnames:
    exim4/dc_postmaster:
    exim4/dc_readhost: '{{ mail_domain }}'
    exim4/dc_relay_domains:
    exim4/dc_relay_nets:
    exim4/dc_smarthost: '{{ mail_server }}'
    exim4/exim4-config-title:
    exim4/hide_mailname: 'false'
    exim4/mailname: '{{ mail_domain }}'
    exim4/no_config: 'false'
    exim4/use_split_config: 'false'
  notify:
    - update exim4 configuration
    - restart exim4
```

I then have to use the following handler with shell script to cause it to re-generate the Exim 4 configuration:

```
- name: "update exim4 configuration"
  become: true
  shell: |
    rm -f /etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf
    dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config -f noninteractive
    /usr/sbin/update-exim4.conf
    exit 0

- name: "restart exim4"
  become: true
  service:
    name: exim4
    enabled: yes
    state: reloaded
```

The problems with this are:

- It takes quite a while to run
- It has change lines every time it is run `changed: [foo.example.com] => (item={'key': 'exim4/hide_mailname', 'value': 'false'})`
- It isn't great using a shell script
- Overly complex, for what feels like it should be a simple thing

Am I missing something, or is it just not something that most people do?

Comment: It's difficult to answer the last two points without knowing the details.  What in particular do you mean by "It isn't great using a shell script"? What in particular is complex?

Answer (score 1):

Q: **"*It takes quite a while to run.*"**

A: Make the installation optional. For example

```yaml
- name: Install exim4
  apt:
    name:
      - exim4
      - exim4-daemon-light
      - exim4-config
    state: present
  when: install_packages|default(false)|bool
  tags: install
```

Install the packages once and omit the task in the next runs.

```sh
shell> ansible_playbook playbook.yml -t install -e "install_packages=true"
```

<sup>(not tested)</sup>

---

Q: **"*It has change lines every time it is run.*"**

> changed: [foo.example.com] => (item={'key': 'exim4/hide_mailname', 'value': 'false'})

A: Debug the problem. Tag the task, dry-run (-C, --check) the playbook and see the changes (-D, --diff). For example

```yaml
- name: configure exim4-config
  debconf:

  ...

  tags: conf
```

```sh
shell> ansible_playbook playbook.yml -t conf -C -D
```

Make sure the handler "update exim4 configuration" doesn't revert the configuration moving in a circle "conf->handler->conf-> ...".